# How to use duplicate labels with cut function in R?

Tags: r

If I have a vector of numbers, I know how to allocate them to categories using the cut function:

```
v<-c(3,2,9,3,4,10,-4) # example vector
c<-cut(v,breaks=c(-10,0,3,8,Inf),labels=c("blue","yellow","green","orange"))
c
[1] yellow yellow orange yellow green  orange blue  
Levels: blue yellow green orange
```

My issue is that I now want to project a range of numbers to color "lables" reusing colors, e.g. to get a stripe effect:

```
c<-cut(v,breaks=c(-10,0,3,8,Inf),labels=c("blue","green","blue","green"))
```

but this gives me an error:

```
factor level [3] is duplicated
```

I expected the *cut* function to project the categories to an index and then use that index to pick out the entry in the labels vector, but that doesn't seem to be the way it works.  Is there a way to use repeated labels with "cut"?

Comment: It should be possible to use repeated labels in future versions of R (either 3.4.2 or 3.5.0). From the [changes in R-devel page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html): *factor(x, levels, labels) now allows duplicated labels (not duplicated levels!). Hence you can map different values of x to the same level directly.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can coerce to numeric, so it's no longer a factor, then use indices to match to your colors:

```
v <- c(3,2,9,3,4,10,-4)
C <- cut(v, breaks = c(-10,0,3,8,Inf))

C <- as.numeric(C)
c("blue","green","blue","green")[C]
```

> ```
> [1] "green" "green" "green" "green" "blue"  "green" "blue"
> ```